# QGIS Desktop window is oversized

Tags: qgis, windows

I have bug with QGIS  version 3.10 (also happenes in 3.8) that I don't know how to fix.
Since few days ago, the desktop screen looks like this:
[image]

It might look fine on first sight, but the qgis window covers the start menu and also I cant close the screen or minimize it because I "lost" the acess to the '-' or 'x' buttons on the top.

I have been told that it might relate to plugins but I couldn't find any solution or solve it.

My end goal: to have the screen on the right size again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try F11 or "View -> FullScreen".
Most probably you are in a fullscreen mode.